# Error when connecting to Oracle from Python using cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle

- Python 3.6.3
- [Oracle InstantClient Basic 12.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html)
- [cx_Oracle 6 Installed per instructions](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#install-using-pip)

I'm attempting to connect to an Oracle db using python 3.6.3 and the above mentioned cx_oracle installation.  It's definitely finding the client and the mentioned vc redistributable as far as I can tell, because I had different errors when I first tried to run it.  Now I'm getting:

`cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1050: Oracle Client library must be at version 11.2 or higher`

Now I'm not really an Oracle guy, so maybe I'm misreading or misunderstanding something.  InstantClient 12.2 is the required client, correct?  And according to the docs cx_oracle 6 is compatible with 11.2, 12.1 and 12.2, so where did I go wrong?

---

#### edit:

- ORACLE_HOME was not set, so I added it, pointed at the InstantClient installation, but it made no difference.
- `cx_oracle.clientversion()` throws the same error as mentioned above.
- For clarity:  This is Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: What does `cx_Oracle.clientversion()` return?

Comment: do you have multiple clients installed perhaps? (maybe an older 9i or 10g Oracle home?)  what does ORACLE_HOME point to?

Comment: How did yiu fix this issue and what was the reason for that?

Comment: I didn't. Ended up being pulled into a different project.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  Make sure you have the `oci.dll` in your path, but rename it to `oci_11_2.dll`